# "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" on for loop, but not in list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I'm writing a code to check if the same index of each list inside a nested list are the same. I tried writing it as a for loop, but i got "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable". Then I tried doing list comprehension and it didn't get the TypeError. I'm new to programming so i don't really know if both expressions are supposed to do the same. Can someone help me realize the difference beetween them and why I'm getting the TypeError with the for loop?
It's supposed to validate a sudoku, so the lenght of the nested list is supposed to be same as the lenght of each sublist.

For loop:

```
for l in nlist:
    if len(set(l[0])) != len(nlist):
        return False
```

List comprehension:

```
validate_nlist = len(set(l[0] for l in nlist)) == len(nlist)
```

Comment: Showing some test lists would greatly help understand the problem better.

Comment: Your parens are different.

Comment: What you wrote in the second snippet isn't a list comprehension at all, and you don't want a list comprehension here anyway.  The equivalent of your `for` loop would be a generator inside an `any()` call, e.g. `return not any(len(set(l[0])) != len(nlist) for l in nlist)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `any` for this instead:

```py
if any(len(set(l[0])) != len(nlist) for l in nlist):
    return False
```